# How to hide title bar of preference fragment in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, preferenceactivity

I want to hide the title bar of a preference fragment and not able to use `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)` as it is only applicable to the full screen activity but not to the Sub Screen.

Can anyone please help with any alternative to hide the title bar of preference fragment?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555914/how-to-remove-the-title-bar-from-preferencecategory-in-preferenceactivity

Answer (score 3):

In your fragment `onCreate()` add the code:

```
ActionBar action=getActivity().getActionBar();
action.hide();
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply Manuel. But your soln is hiding the title of the activity but not of the preference fragment.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the solution to hide the fragment header:

```
((FragmentBreadCrumbs)(findViewById(android.R.id.title))).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Using this in your PreferenceActivity in Android Manifest:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the breadcrumb title which should be removed.

You could create the Headers in a PreferenceActivity in the onBuildHeaders method. A click on a Header then creates the PreferenceFragment. The Header's breadcrumb title can be set to an empty string. This removes the title of the PreferenceFragment.

```
public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
    Header header = new Header();
    header.fragment = "YourPreferenceFragment";
    header.title = "Header title";
    header.breadCrumbTitle = "";
    target.add(header);
}
```